# Create an FTP access to a folder with cPanel, but do not give access to subfolders

Tags: ftp, cpanel, subdirectory

I created an FTP account for a user, to give him access to a specific folder, but I don't want him to access subfolders.
Is that possible?

On the cPanel documentation I only found the following statement, but it doesn't help so much:

> Specify the FTP account's home directory.
>
> The Directory field defines
>   the top level of directory access that
>   will be granted to the new account.
>   For example, an account with a
>   Directory assignment of /$dir will not
>   be allowed to access the / (root)
>   directory; however, it will be able to
>   access /$dir and all of its
>   subfolders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the directory permissions using any FTP program like FileZilla FTP, browse to the folder, right click on it and set the permissions using the permissions menu.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry for the delay, I just found out I forgot to accept this answer!